# Getting a "head: error reading 'path': is a directory" error

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get the first line of a file, but for some reason, the `head` command seems to be called on the parent directory, which obviously won't work.

I have a variable `productPath` which contains the path to the file that I want to analyze. From executing an `echo` on that variable, I determined that the variable does indeed contain the correct path to the file I want to read. However, when I execute the following:

```
line = $(head -n 1 $productPath)
```

I get the following error:

```
head: error reading 'src/test/resources/features/Env_First': Is a directory
```

The file is actually inside the `Env_First` directory. I tried executing `head` on a few other files, and all of them seem to be doing the same thing (always trying to read the parent directory, instead of the actual file). What would be the correct usage of `head` to get the first line of the file?

EDIT:
As per @bhristov's request, here is a minimal reproducible snippet. Here, I'm reading a file called `readableFile.feature` in the directory `src/test/environments`.

```
for productPath in $(find src/test/environments -maxdepth 1)
do
      echo "$productPath" #this outputs src/test/environments/readableFile.feature 
      line=$(head -n 1 $productPath) #this produces the error mentioned earlier
done
```

Comment: What is in $productPath?

Comment: I'm using it in a loop. Basically, it contains the path to the file whose first line I want to read. For example, using the directory I used in te question, $productPath could have a value of "src/test/resources/features/Env_First/Product_First".

Product_First, in turn, would have something like:

"The world is round\n
The world is not flat"

I want to store "The world is round" in a variable

Comment: Could you please show me a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: no, what is the **value** of `$productPath`?  please provide output from `echo "${productPath}"`; if `$productPath` is a **directory** then the error makes sense (ie, asking for the `head` of a directory will generate the same error you're receiving)

Comment: @bhristov I will update the question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @bhristov just updated my post

Comment: how about `find src/test/environments -maxdepth 1 -type f -print -exec head -n1 {} \;`

Comment: @alecxs I seem to be getting a `find: missing argument to -exec` error when do that

Comment: escape the semicolon like in my example (or skip `-print` and use `+` instead of `\;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The find command will return the directory as the first result, which is why the error.

I suggest replacing that `find` with this:

```
for productPath in src/test/environments/*
do
      echo "$productPath" 
      line=$(head -n 1 $productPath) 
done
```

Another option is to add a check before doing whatever you want to do with if to see if `productPath` is a file.

Comment: You are a savior. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Brownman quote `"$productPath"` and add `-type f` or `-not -type d` otherwise it will still give errors. also line will not give 1:1 output unless you quote `"$()"`